# how to increase number of remote desktop connections through registry or command line?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to increase number of remote desktop connections through automation.(number of sessions, overall not for single user).
I can do this manually by from here.
Double click Limit number of connections and set the RD Maximum Connections allowed to 999999.

But I want to do it from regedit or cmd so that I can embed into some scritpts.

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you want to increase? The number of outbound connections from a machine? That is unlimited. The number of concurrent logged on users? That is not a registry setting. Or what else?

Comment: @cdavid edited..